# Calculate real time depending time zone

Tags: php

I have actually:

```
<?php
  $zone = "America/New_York";
  $date = date(Y-m-d H:m:s);
?>
```

How can I convert my `$date` with the actual selected `$zone` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
date_default_timezone_set($zone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here, just maybe someone might find it useful.

You can also manually convert the timezone using gmdate and time() if you know your timezone's difference in hours from GMT.

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:m:s',time()-(5*3600));
```

Comment: We (the English) dictacted GMT - empire building on the high seas or was it down to railways (another English invention). Now it is called UTC just for the Yanks

Comment: BTW - some timezones are not an increment of hrs but 1/2 hrs

Comment: Oh yeah! UTC, thanks for pointing that out. 1/2 hrs? Really? I didn't know that.

Comment: -  Adelaide for example

Comment: Huh... look at that... you learn something everyday. I guess you can do +9.5*3600 with that one.